# Error in doBackground AsyncTask?

Tags: android

I keep getting a error in my doInBackground()

```
07-20 21:05:20.859: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3289): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()


07-20 21:05:20.859: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3289): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Here is my asyncTask method.

```
                private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {try {
                            getImages();
                            Log.v("MyTask", "Image 1 retreived");
                            getImage2();
                            Log.v("MyTask", "Image 2 retreived");
                            getImage3();
                            Log.v("MyTask", "Image 3 retreived");
                            getImage4();
                            Log.v("MyTask", "Image 4 retreived");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("MainMenu retreive image", "Image Retreival failed");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    return null;
                }

                protected Void onPostExecute(){
                    ((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
                            .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainMenu.this));
                    return null;

                }

                        }

}
```

And its still holding up my UI for some reason. the UI doesnt appear till after its done.

Here is my onCreate() where i execute the AsyncTask.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


MyTask myTask = new MyTask();

    myTask.execute();

}
```

Comment: You need to read about the various methods in an `AsyncTask`.  The way you have it written, you're retrieving your images on the UI thread and trying to set your adapter in a separate thread (which is why you're getting the error).

Comment: Your `onPostExecute()` will not be called, because it is not a part of the `AsyncTask`'s interface, because it is not overriding the proper method.  The generics you have specified suggest that your onPostExecute method will take a Void object as a parameter to fulfill the `AsyncTask` contract.  The method declaration should look like this:  `onPostExecute(Void notUsed)`.  This is the reason that the `@Override` annotation is extremely helpful.

Comment: so   @Override protected void onPostExecute(Void notUsed){   return;{

Answer (score 1):

You cannot manipulate the UI while you are not in the UI thread.

[AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

I am going to go out on a limb and guess that your time consuming call is `getImages()`.  If this is the case, these method calls should happen in the `doInBackground()` method, and the code you currently have in the `doInBackground()` method should probably be moved to the `onPostExecute()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yoshi you'll actually want to move everything in your AsynkTask around.  Put the load images functions into the do in background method and then on the setListAdapter call into the onPostExecute method the Doinbackground method can not change or update a view however the onPostexecute should be able to.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Exception error) {
        try {
            if (error == null) {
                ((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
                        .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainMenu.this));

            } else

            throw error;
        } catch (Throwable t) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I do not think you mean to surround this in a `try-catch`.  The `throw error;` line will just be caught in the `catch(Throwable t)`

Comment: @jared look my updated AsyncTask method. the onPostExecute never gets called. only the do in background